Sepharadic Daf Yomi speaker?
I'm looking for a playlist of Daf Yomi from a Sepharadic speaker; I have trouble understanding Ashkanazi Hebrew and I don't want to get my words mixed up.

Would you like recommendations in English or Hebrew?

Either is fine, preferably English

Rabbi Eli Mansour, the head of the Edmond J. Safra Synagogue (a large Syrian congregation in Brooklyn) does a nice Daf Yomi shiur using Sephardic pronunciation and a deep Brooklyn accent.

Yes, iTorah! Fantastic sefardi resource
